# Is there a source that lists English Loanwords into Mandarin Chinese?

Tags: english, resource-request, borrowing, mandarin

Is there a source(database, dataset, etc.) that lists English Loanwords into Mandarin Chinese?

Comment: I think that this question should be posted on the Chinese Language Stack Exchange.   http://chinese.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would help if I knew why you were asking. Do you want to study some phonological aspects of the adoption strategy? Just choose proper names of famous individuals in that case. If you're interested in semantic  and phonological aspects of adoption, it'll be more difficult...